# naked asterisk as parameter in method definition: def f(*)

Tags: ruby, parameters

I know what this means:

```
def f(*args)
  ...
end
```

But what does this mean and why would you want to use it?  Can it appear with named parameters, too?

```
def f(*)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`def f(*)` has the same effect as `def f(*args)`, except that it does not name the globbed argument array. You might use it if you want the function to accept any number of arguments but don't actually need to refer to them within the function -- for example, if you are overriding a method but calling `super` without passing an explicit argument list, which results in the original arguments being passed to `super`.

You can write `def f(a, b, *)` as well.

Comment: +1, thanks!  Do you have any cite or authority for this?  It seems to be _Not Very Well Publicized_ (tm).

Comment: It's not well publicized because typically we'd use `(*args)`. That's the Ruby way.

Comment: @pilcrow: Having arguments but not using any of them would be a slight code smell, so it wouldn't be well publicized.

Comment: is this syntax documented anywhere that you know of?

Comment: The only place I've seen it "officially" documented is the relevant [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/def_spec.rb#L35).

Comment: The RubySpec link has moved: https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/def_spec.rb#L98

Comment: Also: https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/def_spec.rb#L83

Comment: Starting with Ruby 2.0 also properly documented under [Syntax – Methods – Array/Hash Argument](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array-2FHash+Argument): _"Also, note that a bare `*` can be used to ignore arguments"_