# Unnamed *(splat) operator as parameter in a method signatutre

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [naked asterisk as parameter in method definition: def f(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249537/naked-asterisk-as-parameter-in-method-definition-def-f)

I have used the splat operator to declare methods accepting dynamic argument counts, i,e:

```
def foo(*args)
  # do something
  pp args.join(",")
end
```

I came across this [method declaration][1] in rails code.

```
def save!(*)
  create_or_update || raise(RecordNotSaved)
end
```

How does the unnamed splat operator work? How does one act on the passed parameters to the method?